# How to access prefix parameters in closures laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to access a variable in my routes that is defined in a route prefix.

```
Route::group( array('prefix' => '{airline_id}','before' => 'airline'), function($airline_id){

Route::get('/edit', function(){

   // Access $airline_id here...

}

});
```

But it just throws an error saying "Missing argument 1 for {closure}()"...

Is there any way to do this or am I stuck making a bunch of routes..

Comment: isn't prefix suppose to be a non dynamic string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use group route this way on Laravel, you're supposed to preset the prefix:

```
Route::group( array('prefix' => 'swissair','before' => 'airline'), function($airline_id){

    Route::get('/edit', function(){

       // Access $airline_id here...

    }

});
```

But Jason Lewis [Enhanced Router](https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router) can do it for you:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '{locale}'), function()
{
    Route::get('about', function($locale)
    {

    });

    Route::get('/', function($locale)
    {
        return 'Homepage';
    });
})->where('locale', '(en|fr)');
```